# Personalized Return message in R

Tags: r

My goal is to generate a personalized return message with R Markdown. I have an csv file with the needed headers  and  and i want to set the ID Nummer as Input and get the name as an output.
example:

```
CSV File: ID Nr.        Name
          1147          John Doe 

input: 1147...
output:Dear John Doe
```

Comment: So what have you tried and where are you getting stuck? What exactly does your markdown document look like? It seems like you should just be able to read in your CSV and then filter it to get the value you want. How are you setting the input ID? Are you using a report parameter?

Comment: I generated the whole R Markdown and it works, but now my boss wanted to automize the procedure. 
So i wanted to generate a function (and i'm stucking with that) that i can set an input of the ID number and R give me the Name Prename and Birthdayas an output. These are in the same row as the ID number.